# Break out of for loop and return after each round of variables have been echoed

Tags: php, twig, opencart

I have created a function in twig/php to run though a array and return only the figures that that match using an if statement for each range. I have to duplicate this 10 times and was wondering what the best practice is (ie is there a shorter hand or should i stick with this).

```
        <p>Ceiling</p>

        {% for category in categories|sort %}

            {% if category.range == "Ceiling" %} 
                <a href="{{ category.href }}"><li class="SubRange">{{ category.name }}</li></a>
            {% endif %}

        {% endfor %}

        <hr>

        <p>Lamps</p>

        {% for category in categories|sort %}

            {% if category.range == "Lamps" %} 
                <a href="{{ category.href }}"><li class="SubRange">{{ category.name }}</li></a>
            {% endif %}

        {% endfor %}

        <hr>
```

The ranges in this example is Ceiling and Lamps which will only print out in them ranges.

The controller

```
            $data['categories'][] = array(
                'range' => $ProductRange,
                'name' => $result['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($filter_data) . ')' : ''),
                'href' => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '_' . $result['category_id'] . $url)
            );
```

Comment: Where is `$ProductRange` set?

Answer (score 0):

I try to avoid looping through an array twice - it generally means you did not organize your information properly or did not do enough the first time around. In your case, you could sort the categories into lamps and ceiling before sending the information to the template. It would reduce the run time by half if you sort it as you put it into the categories variable since each loop would then run and print everything.

You could even make 'lamps' and 'ceiling' into array keys that hold arrays and run the foreach on categories['lamps'] and categories['ceiling']. Then, you can also display the categories if not empty, and on empty, display an appropriate message

Comment: That's what I done. I have edited it to show my controller

Comment: @Phpuser I meant that, if you structure your data, you can still run two loops. One for each category, but it wont run through everything every time

Answer (score 0):

To eloborate on @Ice76 answer,

<kbd>PHP</kbd>

```
<?php
    $temp = fetchYourCategories();
    $categories_per_range = [];

    foreach($temp as $category) {
        if (!isset($categories[$category->range])) $categories[$category->range] = [];
        $categories[$category->range][] = $category;
    }

    echo $twig->render('template.twig', [ 'categories_per_range' => $categories_per_range, ]);
```

<kbd>Twig</kbd>

```
{% for range, categories in categories_per_range %}
    <h1>{{ range }}</h1>
    {% for category in categories %}
        <a href="{{ category.href }}"><li class="SubRange">{{ category.name }}</li></a>
    {% endfor %}        
    <hr />
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: The product ranges are being looped with the categories.

Comment: It's just an example on how to regroup your data